# How to select all value of datepicker into dynamic tabs

Tags: jquery, datepicker

In tabs-1

```
 $(".datepicker").datepicker('getDate') is value
```

In tabs-2

```
 $(".datepicker").datepicker('getDate') is null
```

So, How to select all value of datepicker into dynamic tabs ?

Comment: What do you mean by tabs-1 and tabs-2? You have two `div` elements, each being a tab? And each one contains a datepicker?

Comment: Please show us all the code.. including html

Answer (score 0):

You should select the picker relative to the parent. Considering each tab has an ID, you should do like this:

For the first tab:

```
 $("#tab1 .datepicker").datepicker('getDate')
```

For the second:

```
 $("#tab2 .datepicker").datepicker('getDate')
```